# Are questions about webfiction on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I've been avidly reading [Worm](http://parahumans.wordpress.com/) and [Pact](http://pactwebserial.wordpress.com/), two very good web serials that are about superheroes and demons respectively (a bit of an oversimplification, but close enough). However, although Worm has been finished at about 1.6 million words and Pact is over 100,000 words and counting, neither have been published.

Are questions about them on topic, given that their subject matter is suitable? Or in a more general sense, is webfiction on-topic?

Comment: I'd disagree - Worm, at least, meets my personal definition of 'published'.  It has a known, easily locatable web site.  It is fairly heavily advertised (primarily by fans) and occupies many high-ranking spots in lists of prominent web fiction.  It isn't a printed book, but it *is* published.

Comment: @Jeff That doesn't cover Pact though. Either way, I was also wondering whether being published or not has to do with financial matters - I remember wildbow stating somewhere that he makes slightly more than minimum wage from fan donations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say that our scope is more defined by genre than by media. If the web fiction is Sci-fi/Fantasy/Speculative, then it's welcome here.

Comment: Agreed. That said, with the proviso that if you're asking questions about something very niche, you probably shouldn't expect the same level of response (or even attention) that more popular tags will get

Comment: Yes, what @Richard said. I've answered a question about a web published story and I'd be willing to bet that there aren't more than one or two other people on this entire site who could have answered it. If that many.

Comment: Thanks! I was mostly concerned because in some cases I've seen, the line between webfiction and fanfiction has been very thin. In the case of Pact and Worm though, that's not an issue.